# NoReverseMatch error with djangorest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am following the djangorest framework tutorial and building up a blog application. However, while I am trying to render data to HTML form, I am facing a 'NoReverseMatch' error.

Below is my models.py

```
from django.db import models

class BlogModel(models.Model):  
    blog_title = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    blog_post = models.TextField(max_length = 100)
    blog_author = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
    blog_tags = models.CharField(max_length = 30)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.blog_title

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('blog_title',)
```

serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from blogg.models import *

class BlogSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = BlogModel
        fields = ('blog_title', 'blog_post', 'blog_author', 'blog_tags')
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from django.http import Http404
from blogg.models import *
from blogg.serializers import *
from rest_framework.renderers import TemplateHTMLRenderer

class BlogList(APIView):    
    serializer_class = BlogSerializer
    renderer_classes = [TemplateHTMLRenderer]
    template_name = 'home.html'
    def get(self, request, format = None):      
        blogs = BlogModel.objects.all()
        #serializer = BlogSerializer(blogs, many = True)
        #return Response(serializer.data)   
        return Response({'blogs':blogs})
    def post(self, request, format = None):     
        serializer = BlogSerializer(data = request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.errors)

class BlogDetail(APIView):  
    serializer_class = BlogSerializer
    renderer_classes = [TemplateHTMLRenderer]
    template_name = "details.html"
    def get_object(self, pk):       
        try:
            return BlogModel.objects.get(pk = pk)
        except BlogModel.DoesNotExist:
            raise Http404

    def get(self, request, pk, format = None):
        blogs = self.get_object(pk)
        serializer = BlogSerializer(blogs)
        #return Response(serializer.data)
        return Response({'serializer':serializer, 'blogs':blogs})

    def put(self, request, pk, format = None):
        blogs = self.get_object(pk)
        serializer = BlogSerializer(blogs, data = request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.errors)

    def delete(self, request, pk, format = None):
        blogs = self.get_object(pk)
        blogs.delete()
        serializer = BlogSerializer(blogs)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from blogg import views
from rest_framework.urlpatterns import format_suffix_patterns


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^blogs/$', views.BlogList.as_view()),
    url(r'^blogs/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.BlogDetail.as_view()),

]

urlpatterns = format_suffix_patterns(urlpatterns)
```

details.html

```
{% load rest_framework %}

<html><body>

<h1>Blog - {{ blogs.title }}</h1>

<form action="{% url 'details' blogs.id %}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% render_form serializer %}
    <input type="submit" value="Save">
</form>

</body></html>
```

Error description:

```
Reverse for 'details' with arguments '(1,)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
```

at line: `<form action="{% url 'details' blogs.id %}" method="POST">`

url i am trying to access :

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/blogg/blogs/1/
```

Could you please help me out of this. Please let me know for any other information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't pass `name` as keyword argument to in your url function in order to use named urls.

Something like this should work fine:

```
url(r'^blogs/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.BlogDetail.as_view(), name='details')
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I resolved this. I have simply added a name to my url and used the same name in template as below

added name attribute in urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from blogg import views
from rest_framework.urlpatterns import format_suffix_patterns


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^blogs/$', views.BlogList.as_view()),
    url(r'^blogs/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.BlogDetail.as_view(), name = 'blog_details'),

]

urlpatterns = format_suffix_patterns(urlpatterns)
```

details.html

```
{% load rest_framework %}

<html><body>

<h1>Blog - {{ blogs.title }}</h1>

<form action="{% url 'blog_details' blogs.id %}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% render_form serializer %}
    <input type="submit" value="Save">
</form>

</body></html>
```

And it's working :)